AWK command to print names of files an hour old
I want to print the file names that start with file from a given directory that are at least 1 hour old using AWK,  the way find /tmp/test/ -mmin +60 does.
Please help me out with the awk command.

Why can't you modify the find with -name 'file*'?

There is no need to use AWK for that, you can use the -printf option, e.g. -printf '%f\n'.

I don't know why you want to use awk for this (and, if you do, why you don't tag the question with awk). If you see this problem as an exercise on learning awk, at least post some code which shows what you tried so far.

https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

In the simplest example,
$: find $dir -maxdepth 1 -name 'file*' -type f -mmin +60 | awk 1

or even
$: find $dir -maxdepth 1 -name 'file*' -type f -mmin +60 | awk '{print}'

...but that's silly, because adding awk to the end of those find commands doesn't change the resulting output at all - it just wastes resources. I have to assume you mean NOT using find.
That's a little harder, but not bad.
Do you have the filefuncs extension available?
If so, this should work:
@load "filefuncs"
BEGIN{ f="/tmp/deleteme"; print f>f; stat(f,t); start=t["mtime"]; system("rm "f); }
{ stat($1,t); if ( (start-t["mtime"]) >= 3600 ) print $1 }

You need to feed it the filenames, but that's easy.
printf '%s\n' $dir/file* | awk -f scriptfile

If you don't have filefuncs available you should still be able to use pipes to read from stat...
BEGIN{ f="/tmp/deleteme"; print f>f; "stat -c '%Y' "f | getline start; system("rm "f); }
{ "stat -c '%Y' "$1 | getline ts; if ( (start-ts) >= 3600 ) print $1 }

Note that these don't check the file types, so if your input includes a directory name it will be checked like any other file. If that's a problem you can add file type to stat's output with %F and check that.

PS:... don't parse from ls.
